# HTML5 : Uknown error when trying to copy a canvas into another one

Tags: html, canvas, drawimage

I can't figure how to make drawImage work... It just does nothing (except that it throws an exception with an undefined description) :

```
layerCtx.globalAlpha = 0,2; // same thing with this line commented
layerCtx.drawImage(cvs, 0 , 0);
```

I have 2 canvas, one is a layer and the other is for drawing using the mouse. I want to save what the user has drawn on the first canvas to the layer and apply opacity...
I won't give you all the code but you have to know that the following code works :

```
layerCtx.putImageData(ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 800, 500), 0, 0);
```

but I can't use opacity with the previous, so as it is advised in other stackoverflow.com related questions, I'd like to use drawImage with a canvas element.

**ctx** is the context for my canvas **cvs**,
**layerCtx** is the context fort my canvas **layer**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're gonna hate this: You wrote `0,2` instead of `0.2`. That's why it isn't working.

I know a comma is used as a decimal in a lot of European countries, but `0.2` is what its gotta be for this.

Working example to check your code by:

http://jsfiddle.net/zC4Wh/